# How to join for multiple collection with specific key using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 table consider
**1. User table**
username, email, userid, objectid
**2. Role table**
objectid, roleid, rolename
**3. User-role table**
objectid, roleid, userid

i need user deatils using mongoose
username, email, userid, rolename
need solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate([

    // Join with user_info table
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "user_role",      
            localField: "userId",   
            foreignField: "userId", 
            as: "user_role"         
        }
    },
    {   $unwind:"$user_role" },     // $unwind used for getting data in object or for one record only

    // Join with user_role table
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "role", 
            localField: "roleId", 
            foreignField: "roleId",
            as: "user_role"
        }
    },
    {   $unwind:"$role" },

    // define some conditions here 
    {
        $match:{
            $and:[{"userid" :1}]
        }
    },

    // define which fields are you want to fetch
    {   
        $project:{
            _id : 1,
            email : 1,
            userName : 1,
            userPhone : "$user_info.phone",
            role : "$user_role.role",
        } 
    }
])
```

Comment: first lookup understood but second one not able to understand,
can u explain above asked table wise

Comment: First level join like user + user role table done but need to join user role with role table i am not able to do can u help me on this